# Rate of convergence of a solution to an equation with a free parameter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\epsilon>0$ is a solution to the following equation:
$$\epsilon^2-a(m)\ln\epsilon-b(m)=0,$$
where $a(m)\to 0^+$ and $b(m)\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$.

Suppose that a solution $\epsilon=\epsilon(m)$ exists for each $m$ sufficiently large. I'm interested in its behavior as $m\to\infty$. Can we state a rate of convergence of $\epsilon(m)$ in terms of $a(m)$ and $b(m)$?

By the definition I derived that $\epsilon(m)$ must tend to zero, and in particular that $a(m)\ln\epsilon(m)\to 0$, so $\epsilon(m)$ must go to zero more slowly than $\exp\{-1/a(m)\}$. I can't easily find an upper bound though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is strictly positive, the substitution $\epsilon = x\sqrt{a}$ transforms the equation into $$x^2 - \ln{x} = \frac{\ln{a}}{2} + \frac{b}{a}$$

The rate of convergence depends on how the RHS behaves.

For example, if $b = a^{\alpha}$, it foes to infinity approximately as $a^{\alpha - 1}$, and $x \approx a^{\frac{\alpha - 1}{2}}$ that is $\epsilon = a^{\frac{1}{2}} x \approx a^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks, fixed